# Can i get events from normal keyboard presses with the logitech lua api?

Tags: lua, logitech, logitech-gaming-software

I have a G513 which means i cannot simply remap most of the buttons. i was thinking of detecting a button press and then press another button with logitech lua but i cannot find an event for it. is remapping even possible in this case? I would not want to use ahk for this as i only want it for one game and ahk is bannable in this one

Comment: No.  You can remap or set Lua handler only for F1-F12.

Comment: LGS is safe.  This means you are unable to write a keylogger or other potentially dangerous scripts.  Safety is necessary to enable free exchange of LGS scripts between players.